# rstan C++14 error while installing (centos)

Tags: r, gcc, c++14, rstan

while installing rstan getting following error:

```
Error in .shlib_internal(args) :
C++14 standard requested but CXX14 is not defined
```

from research got to know that C++14 compiler should be available. 
How to install the same while configuring R. 
    Using the below command to configure R

```
./configure --with-readline=no --with-x=no
```

and installing

```
yum install -y devtoolset-6
```

but still not able to update C++14 and rstan gives the error

```
Default C++ compiler:      g++   -g -O2
C++98 compiler:            g++  -g -O2
C++11 compiler:            g++ -std=gnu++11 -g -O2
C++14 compiler:            g++   -g -O2  
C++17 compiler:              
Fortran 90/95 compiler:    gfortran -g -O2
Obj-C compiler:
```

setup.sh

```
 yum -y update
 yum install -y centos-release-scl
 yum install -y devtoolset-6
 yum install -y devtoolset-6-gcc-gfortran
 scl enable devtoolset-6 bash
 scl enable devtoolset-6-gcc-gfortran bash
 mkdir packages
 cd packages
 wget -qO- 
 https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/libpng/zlib/1.2.8/zlib- 
 1.2.8.tar.gz | tar zvx
 cd zlib-1.2.8
 ./configure
 make
 make install
 cd ..
 wget -qO- http://downloads.sourceforge.net/pcre/pcre-8.35.tar.gz | 
 tar xzv
 cd pcre-8.35
 ./configure
 make
 make install
 cd ..
 wget -qO- http://tukaani.org/xz/xz-5.2.2.tar.gz | tar xzv
 cd xz-5.2.2
 ./configure
 make
 make install
 cd ..
 wget -qO- https://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.47.1.tar.gz | tar xzv
 cd curl-7.47.1
 ./configure
 make
 make install
 cd ..


 wget -qO- https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-3/R-3.4.4.tar.gz | 
 tar xzv
 cd R-3.4.4
 ./configure --with-readline=no --with-x=no --prefix=/packages/R-3.4.4 
 F77=gfortran
 make
 make install
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I also got this problem, here I record how to solve it.

The key point is installing proper g++ and configure it.

Firstly, install g++ Version >= 5 as https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/wiki/Installing-RStan-on-Linux said:

> Using RStan requires either g++ version 4.9 and up

Here I am installing g++8 (You can change the version as your wish):

Run

```
$ sudo yum install centos-release-scl
$ sudo yum install devtoolset-8-gcc*
```

Now you have an alternative g++ along with default g++ in your OS.

You can enable this and check the version:

```
$ scl enable devtoolset-8 bash
$ gcc --version
$ g++ --version
```

Find its location:

```
$ which g++
/opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/bin/g++
```

Next, you need to configure `~/.R/Makevars`, put the following content to it either using vim (or other editors):

```
CXX14FLAGS=-O3 -march=native -mtune=native -fPIC
CXX14=/opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/bin/g++
```

Or using R commands:

```
dotR <- file.path(Sys.getenv("HOME"), ".R")
if (!file.exists(dotR)) dir.create(dotR)
M <- file.path(dotR, "Makevars")
if (!file.exists(M)) file.create(M)
cat("\nCXX14FLAGS=-O3 -march=native -mtune=native -fPIC",
    "CXX14=/opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/bin/g++", # or clang++ but you may need a version postfix
    file = M, sep = "\n", append = TRUE)
```

> NOTE: these R commands are copied from https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/wiki/Configuring-C-Toolchain-for-Linux but CXX14 flag is modified according to the location above.

Now, you can install `rstan` package now:

```
install.packages("rstan")
```

Hope this helps.

---

PS: R users can use this approach to modify the compiler flags in a similar way.

Comment: I believe this link is no longer functioning.

Comment: @Caddisfly Thanks for pointing out, I have updated.

Comment: Is the path to g++ only requirement? devtoolset has own versions of make or valgrind. I was using scripts with all toolset enable but your configuration is very convenient.

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me:

CXX_STD = CXX14

CXX14 = g++ -std=c++11

CXX14FLAGS = -O3 -fPIC -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-function -DBOOST_PHOENIX_NO_VARIADIC_EXPRESSION

Comment: Which file should this write to?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to recompile R but you do need at least g++-4.9 (or clang++-3.4) and to define `CXX14 = g++` in your ~/.R/Makevars configuration file. In addition, you usually need `CXX14FLAGS = -fPIC` and would be well advised to have `CXX14FLAGS = -O3 -mtune = native -march = native -fPIC`. There is a wiki [page](https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/wiki/Installing-RStan-on-Linux) for all this.

Answer (score 1):

did the following changes and now it's working fine. Need to define gcc PATH and used yum install -y devtoolset-6 for R-3.4.4. Thank you for help

```
yum install -y centos-release-scl
yum install -y devtoolset-6
yum install -y bzip2-devel
source scl_source enable devtoolset-6

also added the Path to gcc in build.sh 

export PATH=/opt/rh/devtoolset-6/root/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Here is my solution in case it helps others.

On CentOS 7, I:

1. installed V8 headers and shared library from here: https://pkgs.org/download/v8-devel 41 (EPEL_x86_64)
2. bumped gcc from version 4 to 9.3.1

In R, I:

1. removed rstan and StanHeaders
2. installed rstan and StanHeaders in a fresh R session

Posted discussion on Stan Forum here: https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/problem-installing-rstan-2-21-using-r-4-0-1-on-centos-7/17784/9