# Couldn't install packages in R on Linux Redhat (CXX14 is not defined)

Tags: r, linux, redhat, r-package, install.packages

I need install 'metaSEM' package in R. It's not allowed to use internet so I tried to use install by the souce file. But it doesn't work. The warning shows as :
ERROR: dependency 'OpenMX' is not availabe for package.

[image]

Could you please give my any suggestion about this situation? Thanks a lot.

Comment: already tried `install.packages('OpenMx')`?

Comment: I have tried and OpenMx couldn't be installed either, which shows ERROR in .shilb_internal(args): C++ 14 standard requested but CXX14 is not defined.

Comment: Strongly looks to me as if GCC has the wrong version or isn't installed at all. Can you check `gcc --version` in a terminal and report back?

Comment: Thank you for reminding. gcc (GCC) is 4.8.5 (redhat 4.8.5-44)

Comment: That's a very old version of the compiler (released 2015!). You may want to [install `devtoolset`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47227183/6574038) if you are admin, which should install gcc 14. You probably need `devtoolset-8` and not `devtoolset-7` though. However, old gcc might (should) remain on your system, since other packages might need it. After installation you probably need to edit `~/.R/Makevars` with `CXX14` entries, which is documented [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58024237/6574038).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I'm not the admin but still many thanks.